# Solving specific Nonlinear Systems of product of variables with real values between 0 and 1

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I was wondering whether the exists a well-known solution for solving non-linear systems in the following form for each of the $n$ variables $x_i$:

$$\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\mathbf{1}_{C_{i}\neq 0}+|S_{i}|}\left (C_{i}+\sum_{k\in S_{i}}\prod_{j=1}^n B_{kj}x_j\right)=x_{i} & S_i\neq \emptyset \\
x_i = C_i & \textrm{oth.}\end{cases}$$

where $S_{i}\in\wp(\{1,\dots,n\})$  , $0\leq C_{\alpha_i}\leq 1$,  $B_{ij}=0\vee B_{ij}=1$, and $\mathbf{1}_p$ is the indicator function returning $1$ when $p$ holds and 0 otherwise.

An example of such a system would be the following one:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}+x)=y\\
\frac{1}{2}(\frac{3}{10}+xy)=z\\
xyz = t\\
\frac{1}{2}(1+ty)=x
\end{cases}$$

Given that my field of research is not mathematics, I would not even know where to start looking for this as, if such kinds of systems are known, I don't know a name for these. If, on the other hand, such systems are known, I would like to know whether some known resolution methods might also be computed by a computer.

Comment: These are systems of polynomial (or algebraic) equations. They can be systematically reduced to polynomial equations in a single variable by eliminating the other variables between the equations, using [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) or [Gröbner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis). The posted example is quintic in $x,y$, cubic in $z$ and quadratic in $t$ e.g. the quadratic in $t$ is derived [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7B2x-4y%2B1%2C10xy-20z%2B3%2Cxyz-t%2C2x-ty%2B1%7D%2C%7Bt%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%2Cz%7D%5D) with roots $t=0, 4$.

Comment: Thanks. Still, I had a different result by asking to solve the system to WolframAlpha, as it got that one possible solution was $t\approx 0.07$ and not $0$: [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+0.5*%280.5%2Bx%29%3Dy+and+0.5*%280.3%2Bx*y%29%3Dz+and+x*y*z%3Dt+and+0.5*%281%2Bt*y%29%3Dx++for+%28x%2Cy%2Cz%2Ct%29+real) . Is maybe WolframAlpha using a different way to solve this then?

Comment: I had a typo in the previous link, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7B2x-4y%2B1%2C10xy-20z%2B3%2Cxyz-t%2C2x-ty-1%7D%2C%7Bt%7D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%2Cz%7D%5D) is the right one, which matches what you got (with the correction to my first comment that it's a *quintic* in $t$ too). Not in this case, but in general one difference is that elimination e.g. `GroebnerBasis` produces an *exact* polynomial, while asking to solve the system lets WA decide how, usually at machine precision, so the results may not always match between the two.

Comment: Very nice, thanks for this!